# SQL Server 2008 Database Design

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

Background: In SQL Server, my database table only has three columns:

- `DataID (PK, bigint)`
- `ProductName (Nchar20)`
- `Price (float)`

Every day it will automatically insert about 5000+ rows of data into this table. Later on this table may add more columns like `AdjustedPrice (float)`, `Discount (float)`...

Question: I know I should probably make `ProductName` as FK to another table (`ProductNameTable` with `ProductID (PK,int)` and `ProductName (Nchar)`, but what about the `price (float)`? Price are depends, could range to 100 - 1000, should I make it FK to another table or just leave it alone in the table?

Any advice from DBA? Thank you sooooo much.....

Comment: Side notes: please don't use `nchar(n)` - those are **fixed-length** strings, they'll **always** take the configured length (times two) of space (padded by spaces). Use `nvarchar(n)` (**variable-length**) instead! Also: for a price, I wouldn't use `float` - this is inherently inaccurate and prone to rounding errors - use `decimal(p,s)` instead!

Comment: Never use float for anything you may calculate on. Price can be date specific so you may need ot consider a start and end date for the price.  If you do not do that make sure to store the price at the time of the order (or purchase depending on what you are doing) in the order table. You need to read up a bit on how to handle temporal data for this design or you will have data integrity problems down the road. suggest you look at books like: http://www.amazon.com/Managing-Time-Relational-Databases-Temporal/dp/0123750415/ref=pd_sim_b_1?ie=UTF8&refRID=0CTVSWVM6466WM465DW3

Comment: Thanks @HLGEM I read that DB should not store statistics column, like MeanOfPrice, SumOfPrice, but why? Bec Integrity or Size Limit?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. No. Price is an atmic element. But my advice would be to get a copy of the Data Model Ressoure Book volume 1 - it discusses database schemata for pricing engines. A good read.

Comment: Thanks, how about if I want to add some statistics column, like MeanOfPrice(DECIMAL), SumOfPrice(DECIMAL)? Why not? Thanks again